# Can a auto finance company refuse to give me a copy of my contract or balance details?

Tags: california

Can a car company refuse to give me a copy of my payment history and balance details?

Comment: Was the mention of "contract" in the title a mistake, or did you make a mistake in the body of the question? That is, what are you asking about?

Comment: What do you mean by "car company"? It sounds like you have purchased a car and financed it and the "car company" is the lender on the loan you took out to purchase the car, which probably isn't the same as the company that sold you the car even though they may be affiliated. Finance companies that lend to consumers are regulated in ways that companies that sell cars are not, so you may have a right to this information under laws pertaining to consumer finance companies.

Answer (score 1):

The car company (or anyone else) is not responsible for acting as your record keeper or bookkeeper - that's your responsibility. So, no.

That said, I cannot think of any reason whey they would refuse such a request. They may be able to request a fee for doing so.

Of course, if you were in dispute with them these are certainly things you could subpoena.